# Hide jqGrid based on User Roles in Asp.net aspx Webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

```
    $(document).ready(){
    BindGrid();
    }
```

Need to show/hide this Grid based on User Roles- if user has “Admin” role then show grid else hide.

Please Note: I tried User.IsInRole(“Admin”) and it’s not working in aspx webforms.
Please help.